# Marketing Developer Platform - Usage of Test Organizations

Tags: linkedin-api

I have applied for the Marketing Developer Platform product to my linkedin application. It's still in review

I have been trying to post shares to test Organization pages through linkedin v2 API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations#test-organizations)

1. with new OAuth v2 authenticated users without w_organization_social scope 
   But I'm getting a response as access denied.

   {
   "serviceErrorCode": 100,
   "message": "Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/owner]",
   "status": 403
   }
2. with old authenticated users with the scope of rw_company_admin scope
   But I'm getting a response as access denied.

   {
       "serviceErrorCode": 100,
       "message": "Not enough permissions to access: POST /shares",
       "status": 403
   }

Do I need to get approved first for the marketing developer API Access to post to test organizations?

Or is there another way for accessing marketing API without approval from linkedin?

I have applied on April 26, they said that it might take around 90 days to get it approved. Is somebody got approved lesser time than 90 days?

To migrate my users to v2 API, do I need to force my users to reauthenticate with OAuth with the new scope?

On May 1st, linkedin is going to deprecate its V1 API. So do I need to get my users reauthenticate again with the company permissions once I get approved?

How to apply for programmatic refresh tokens API access, does marketing developer platform includes it or I have to apply it separately? If so please post the link for it.

Comment: I have the same issue, my application do not work no more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I need to get approved first for the marketing developer API Access to post to test organizations?

```
Yes, Now I got my linkedin approved for "Marketing Developer Platform" Product under Products in my app dashboard. You can apply to the same by "Add Products"
```

Or is there another way for accessing marketing API without approval from linkedin?

```
For now, no other way to get around this. Comment below if you know.
```

I have applied on April 26, they said that it might take around 90 days to get it approved. Is somebody got approved lesser time than 90 days?

```
They got me approved within 20 days which very decent review time.
```

To migrate my users to v2 API, do I need to force my users to reauthenticate with OAuth with the new scope?

On May 1st, linkedin is going to deprecate its V1 API. So do I need to get my users reauthenticate again with the company permissions once I get approved?

```
No, your old API tokens will be valid till their expiry time. After that, your users have to reauthenticate to use your app. Make sure that linkedin API version endpoints are active.
```

How to apply for programmatic refresh tokens API access, does marketing developer platform includes it or I have to apply it separately? If so please post the link for it.

```
No, for "programmatic refresh tokens API access" you have to apply separately.
```